# How to merge two rows having null values into one row replacing null values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm having the following results from my sql query:

| id | sp_firstname | sp_lastname | member_firstname | member_lastname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | John | Smith |
| 2 | Dejuan | McLaughlin | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | Jack | Sparrow |
| 3 | John | Walker | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | Sherlock | Holmes |
| 4 | Mellie | Durgan | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | John | Waston |
| 5 | Lucy | Snider | NULL | NULL |

Whereas what I need to achieve is this:

| id | sp_firstname | sp_lastname | member_firstname | member_lastname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | John | Smith |
| 2 | Dejuan | McLaughlin | Jack | Sparrow |
| 3 | John | Walker | Sherlock | Holmes |
| 4 | Mellie | Durgan | John | Waston |
| 5 | Lucy | Snider | NULL | NULL |

Basically, I need to somehow merge pairs of rows that sort of have `null`s crosswise.

After looking through SO answers, I could only find variants of this problem when `NULL` values needed to be substituted by numbers, and in that case people used `max` function combined with `group by`.

However I have several joins in my table and my `NULL` values need to be substituted with strings, not numbers, so `max` wouldn't really work here (as I thought).

Here's my sql code:

```sql
select
    meeting.id,
    (case when salesprofile.userid = "user".id then "user".firstname end) as sp_firstname,
    (case when salesprofile.userid = "user".id then "user".lastname end) as sp_lastname,
    (case when business.userid = "user".id then "user".firstname end) as member_firstname,
    (case when business.userid = "user".id then "user".lastname end) as member_lastname
from
    meeting
    join project on project.id = meeting.projectid
    left join business on business.id = project.businessid
    left join salesprofile on salesprofile.id = meeting.salesprofileid
    join "user" on "user".id = business.userid or "user".id = salesprofile.userid
group by
    "user".id,
    business.userid,
    meeting.id,
    salesprofile.userid;
```

These firstnames and lastnames come from the exact same `user` table, but they are taken based on different relations found in the same `meeting` table.

Basically, one `meeting` has two `user`s: `member` and `sp`. And I needed a way to get meetings along with its `member` and `sp` users in one row.

---

How can I modify my sql query so that it would merge these pairs of rows with crosswise `null`s into one row with data and without `null`s?

Comment: Max will work just fine with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
select meeting.id,
       max(case when salesprofile.userid = "user".id then "user".firstname end) as sp_firstname,
       max(case when salesprofile.userid = "user".id then "user".lastname end) as sp_lastname,
       max(case when business.userid = "user".id then "user".firstname end) as member_firstname,
       max(case when business.userid = "user".id then "user".lastname end) as member_lastname
from meeting join
     project
     on project.id = meeting.projectid left join
     business
     on business.id = project.businessid left join
     salesprofile
     on salesprofile.id = meeting.salesprofileid left join
     "user"
     on "user".id = business.userid or "user".id = salesprofile.userid
group by meeting.id;
```

Note the change to the `group by` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your results with an outer query to aggregate the columns using `max` and group by the `id`

```
 select id, Max(sp_firstname) as sp_firstname, Max(sp_lastname) as sp_lastname...
 from (
  <inner query>
 )x
 group by id
```